# How to sort different data types in java and print them in a table ? (using method overloading)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, overloading

The objective is to input "any data type" using a java method overloading. After the value has been taken, another method will sort the data according to it's data type in different arrays. After the all the data has been entered and stored in arrays, it has to be printed onto a table.

Eg:

`data(23)`  - this will store integer value to an array

`data(34.453)` - this will store the double value to an array

`data("hello world")` - this will store string value to array

Considering that array size in java are predefined, the table should not print the null or 0 values. All the null/0 values should be excluded while printing.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem:

- We can use the method overloading to capture all data
- Each method will use a different data type but will have the same name - data()
- The number of null values of each array should be found out.
- the variable n will determine which is the largest size among all the 3 integers.
- n will be the test expression limit when printing the table

```
public class overLoadEg {
//array that will store integers
    static int[] intArray = new int[10];
//array that will store doubles
    static double[] doubleArray = new double[10];
//array that will store strings
    static String[] stringArray = new String[10];
    static int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, m, n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//input values
        data(23);
        data(23.4554);
        data("Hello");
        data("world");
        data("help");
        data(2355);
        data(52.56);
        data("val");
        data("kkj");
        data(34);
        data(3);
        data(2);
        data(4);
        data(5);
        data(6);
        data(7);
        data(8);
        display();
    }


    public static void data(int val){
        //add int value to int array
        intArray[i] = val;
        System.out.println("Int " + intArray[i] + " added to IntArray");
        i++;
    }
    public static void data(Double val){
        //add double value to double array
        doubleArray[j] = val;
        System.out.println("Double " + doubleArray[j] + " added to doubleArray");
        j++;
    }
    public static void data(String val){
        //add string value to stringarray
        stringArray[k] = val;
        System.out.println("String " + stringArray[k] + " added to stringArray");
        k++;
    }

    public static void max(){
        //To get the maximum number of values in each array
        int x, y, z;
        x = y = z = 0;

        //counting all the null values in each array and storing in x, y and z
        for(m=0;m<10;m++){
            if(intArray[m] == 0){
                ++x; 
            }
            if(doubleArray[m] == 0){
                ++y;
            }
            if(stringArray[m] == null){
                ++z;
            }
        }

        //subtracting the null/0 count from the array size
        //this gives the active number of values in each array
        x = 10 - x;
        y = 10 - y;
        z = 10 - z;


        //comparing all 3 arrays and check which has the max number of values
        //the max numbe is stored in n
        if(x > y){
            if(x > z){
                n = x;
            }
            else{
                n = z;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(y > z){
                n = y;
            }
            else{
                n = z;
            }
        }
        
    }

    public static void display(){
        //printing the arrays in table
        //All the null/0 values are excluded

        System.out.println("\n\nInt\tDouble\t\tString");
        max();
        for(m = 0; m < n; m++){
            System.out.println(intArray[m] + "\t" + doubleArray[m] + "\t\t" + stringArray[m]);
        }
        System.out.println("Count : " + m);
    }

    
}
```